# Html5 javascript gettime() from <input type="date" />,oddly working

Tags: javascript, html

I am posting date object as unix timestamp.I use getTime() in javascript.

For example

when initializing in my .js file

as

```
firstDate = new Date("2019-08-04");
```

And then when I change value over date input

and firstDate.getTime() this returns timestamp without adding TimezoneOffset.

But without firstDate = new Date("2019-08-04"); assingnation,

when I change value over date input,It adds TimezoneOffset.

So For resolving this issue,I use

```
var timestamp = firstDate.getTime() - 60000 * firstDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

before posting timestamp to the server.

What is the reason of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how it works.As the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date 
says Iso 8601 date constructor is intrepreted as utc not local.So gettime() function generates unix timestamp without adding timezone.Even if i deleted input date value that was assigned in javascript while initializing javascript file and reselect new date value ,it again uses utc.So I do not need substract timezone.

Answer (score 0):

When you set firstDate with the date constructor providing a value "2019-08-04", it will set the date in firstDate to 4th august 2019 and the time to your local time zone (ie, if you are in India, firstDate will be Sun Aug 04 2019 05:30:00 instead of Sun Aug 04 2019 00:00:00). When you call getTime() with out assigning it will add the current date and time with local time zone offset.

Comment: But without using date constructor,it adds timezone.With using date constructor it does not add timezone.